# Why does coord_equal break my heatmap

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap out of the following data:

```
> head(myData.aggregated)
             datetime value       date                time
1 2016-03-31 14:19:00     3 2016-03-31 2016-06-11 14:19:00
2 2016-03-31 14:49:00    69 2016-03-31 2016-06-11 14:49:00
3 2016-03-31 15:49:00     5 2016-03-31 2016-06-11 15:49:00
4 2016-03-31 16:19:00     7 2016-03-31 2016-06-11 16:19:00
5 2016-03-31 17:49:00     2 2016-03-31 2016-06-11 17:49:00
6 2016-03-31 18:19:00     7 2016-03-31 2016-06-11 18:19:00

> tail(myData.aggregated)
              datetime value       date                time
90 2016-04-06 13:19:00     1 2016-04-06 2016-06-11 13:19:00
91 2016-04-06 13:49:00    25 2016-04-06 2016-06-11 13:49:00
92 2016-04-06 14:19:00     7 2016-04-06 2016-06-11 14:19:00
93 2016-04-06 14:49:00     1 2016-04-06 2016-06-11 14:49:00
94 2016-04-06 22:19:00     3 2016-04-06 2016-06-11 22:19:00
95 2016-04-06 22:49:00    14 2016-04-06 2016-06-11 22:49:00
```

And the following ggplot2 commands.

```
ggplot(myData.aggregated, aes(x = time, y = date, fill = scale(value))) + geom_tile() + coord_equal()
```

As soon as I add coord_equal() the result is a blank graph. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how I can fix it. My goal is to get a heatmap with square tiles for each 30 min interval.

Update 1:

```
> dput(head(myData.aggregated))
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1459426740, 1459428540, 
1459432140, 1459433940, 1459439340, 1459441140), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(3L, 69L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 7L), date = structure(c(16891, 
16891, 16891, 16891, 16891, 16891), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(1465647540, 
1465649340, 1465652940, 1465654740, 1465660140, 1465661940), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("datetime", "value", "date", 
"time"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please into your question the output of `dput(myDataSample)` where `myDataSample` is a sample of your data frame that shows the same problem when run with your code.

Comment: What is `x` in `scale(x)`? Did you mean `scale(value)`?

Comment: exactly, I meant `scale(value)`

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** The y-axis spans six units and the x-axis spans tens-of-thousands of units. When you add `coord_equal`, the y-axis gets squashed to roughly 1/10,000th the physical length of the x-axis, effectively making the plot area disappear. The `date` column (y-axis) happens to be in days and the `time` column (x-axis) in seconds, but both are treated as unitless numbers by ggplot. You can denominate the y-axis in seconds also, but that will still give you a plot with an undesirable aspect ratio of at least 6:1. See below for code and additional detail.

---

Here's what's happening: `date` is in `Date` format and is therefore denominated in days, with a range of 6 days. `time` is in `POSIXct` format, which is denominated in seconds, with a range (since we're only interested in the time of day, regardless of date) of tens-of-thousands of seconds (up to a maximum of 86,400 seconds, or the length of one day).

The underlying values of `Date` and `POSIXct` formats are just numeric values with, respectively, `Date` and `POSIXct` classes attached. As a result, when you add `coord_equal`, one unit on the y-axis takes up the same physical distance as 1 unit on the x-axis because ggplot (apparently) calculates `coord_equal` based on the numeric magnitudes of the values, without regard to their date-time class. But the entire y-axis spans 6 units while the x-axis spans tens-of-thousands of units. Thus, when you require `coord_equal`, the y:x aspect ratio gets squashed to on the order of 1:10,000 or so, making the plot disappear for all practical purposes.

You can denominate both the x and y axes in seconds, but even then the y-axis will span at least six times the range (6 days) as the x-axis (maximum of one day), resulting in a y:x aspect ratio of at least 6:1 with `coord_equal`, which is better than 1:10,000, but still not very practical.

Here's an example with fake data:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(4959)
dat = data.frame(datetime=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-03-31"), as.POSIXct("2016-04-06"), by="hour"))
dat$value = sample(1:50, nrow(dat), replace=TRUE)

ggplot(dat, 
       aes(x = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(datetime) %% 86400, 
                          tz="UTC", origin=as.Date("2016-01-01")), 
           y = as.POSIXct(as.Date(datetime)), 
           fill = scale(value))) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  labs(y="Date", x="Time") + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels="%H:%m") +
  coord_equal()
```

In the code above, to create the y values we first convert to `Date` format, which eliminates the time of day and then convert back to `POSIXct` which converts the unit to seconds, but with time equal to midnight on that day for all `datetime` values on a given date.

To create the x values, we just want time of day in seconds after midnight, so we calculate the remainder of the numeric value of `datetime` after division by 86400 (number of seconds in a day). The `tz=UTC` is necessary to get the hours right and `origin` (which can be any date; we just want the time of day) is necessary to get the function to run without an error.

Below is what the plot looks like with and without `coord_equal`. Note that with `coord_equal` the x-axis, which spans one day of time (from midnight to midnight) has the same length as one day on the y axis. That's because we denominated both the y and x values in seconds. However, as long as the y axis spans several days and the x-axis spans only one day, `coord_equal` will result in an undesirable aspect ratio.

[image]

Below is a demonstration of how the y-axis gets squashed relative to the x-axis if the y values are denominated in days rather than seconds and `coord_equal` is specified:

```
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(x = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(datetime) %% 86400, 
                          tz="UTC", origin=as.Date("2016-01-01")), 
           y = as.Date(datetime), 
           fill = scale(value))) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  labs(y="Date", x="Time") + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels="%H:%m") + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]