# Geom tile collapses along Y-axis when adding coord_equal()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series data (currently on monthly frequency) from 2014 up to 2020. That means at most 84 monthly values.

For example when plotting (two of categories from the time series data) using geom_tile, I would have a visual below.

```
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'),each = 84)
n <- rep(round(runif(84,1,4)), 3)
datetime <- rep(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-01"), by="month"), 3)
df <- tibble(ID,n, datetime)
ggplot(df ,
       aes(x=datetime,y=ID,fill=n))+
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

I want the rectangle to be a square, so I add on `coord_equal()` to my `ggplot`,
but somehow the heatmap collapses along the Y-axis

```
ggplot(df ,
       aes(x=datetime,y=ID,fill=n))+
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis() + coord_equal()
```

[image]

The expectation is something like below. As you can see, the squares are of equal size across.

[image]

Comment: This may be useful to go through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768241/why-does-coord-equal-break-my-heatmap

Comment: @RonakShah, let me get a rep data. Will update

Comment: @Aman noted on the ratio, but it doesn't help because we don't have always the luxury where the aspect ratio between y and x are close to 1 though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for why the tile map collapses are well explained in the excellent answer by [@eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768241/why-does-coord-equal-break-my-heatmap) on the same issue. As the reason is that one unit on the x-axis is by default translated into one unit on the y-axis you could prevent the collapsing of your tile map by setting the conversion `ratio` according to the ranges of the x and y scale:

```r
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'),each = 84)
n <- rep(round(runif(84,1,4)), 3)
datetime <- rep(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-01"), by="month"), 3)
df <- data.frame(ID,n, datetime)

library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
ggplot(df ,
       aes(x=datetime,y=ID,fill=n))+
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  coord_equal(ratio = diff(range(as.numeric(datetime))) / length(unique(ID)))
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense after all, but I'm looking for a perfect square for each tile Ref here https://www.royfrancis.com/a-guide-to-elegant-tiled-heatmaps-in-r-2019/. notice that the basic geom_tile() plot (in blue-gray) has nice squares across all states.

Comment: Yep. Makes sense to me. I#m a bit busy at the moment but you could try `coord_equal(ratio = diff(range(as.numeric(datetime))) / length(unique(datetime)))`. This should give you square tiles but also a lot of white space which could only be fixed by adjusting the aspect ratio.